# About list query of mongoose or mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a **Student collection** and a **Class collection**，the class collection have a **studentRefs**，which is a list of student **ids**, but the student don't have a property which refers to **class id**.

Now, I have another list of student ids, and I want to get their classes. I wonder how can I query the classes in mongoose or mongoDB.
The schema in mongoose looks like follow.

```
classSchema = Schema({
    className: String,
    studentRefs: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'students'}]
});
studentSchema = Schema({
    studentName: String
});
```

For example,

Student `A` and `B` are in `Class1`,
Student `C` and `D` are in `Class2`,
Student `E` and `F` are in `Class3`.
Now, I have a arrary `[A, B, C]`.

I want to get the classes of students in that array.
So, my expected result is `[Class1, Class2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator with array fields like `studentRefs` too.  So assuming `studentIds` contains the list of student ids to find the classes for:

```
Class.find({studentRefs: {$in: studentIds}}, function(err, classes) { ... });
```